# Does referencing to a UnityScript file copy its contents?

Tags: performance, memory, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Sorry for the question title is not clear, feel free to edit it if you find a way to describe my question better, which is:

I have two UnityScript files (in Unity 3D), say one is the master and the other is slave, namely Master.js and Slave.js.

Master.js has some `GameObject` type references like this:

```
var myObject_1:GameObject = GameObject.Find("1st object");
var myObject_2:GameObject = GameObject.Find("2nd object");
```

and in Slave.js , I reference the Master Script like this:

```
var masterScript : Master = GameObject.Find("Container").GetComponent(Master);
```

now, does this second reference creates second copies of `myObject_1` and `myObject_2` ?

So am I duplicating the memory use by referencing the script?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are merely getting a reference to the script, which allows you to interact with it.

Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to interact with it, as you'd apply changes to a 'local' copy which the other copy doesn't know about.